# Append Key Value to Associative Array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array:

```
$data["messages"][] = array("chatId" => $chat_id, "type" => "text", "to" => $username, "body" => "success");
```

When print_r the array it looks like this:

```
Array ( [messages] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [chatId] => d3a611401de00e8c8b3e225a7cf95484033f57ea18c442249ee9b5bcb63c9a96 [type] => text [to] => pitashi [body] => success ) ) )
```

But when I try to append the new key value to the end like this:

```
$arr_keyboards[] = array(
    "type" => "suggested",
    "responses" => array(
    array("type" => "text", "body" => "Yes"), 
        array("type" => "text", "body" => "No")
        )

);

$data["messages"]["keyboards"] = $arr_keyboards;
```

I end up with this:

```
Array ( [messages] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [chatId] => d3a611401de00e8c8b3e225a7cf95484033f57ea18c442249ee9b5bcb63c9a96 [type] => text [to] => pitashi [body] => success ) [keyboards] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [type] => suggested [responses] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [type] => text [body] => Yes ) [1] => Array ( [type] => text [body] => No ) ) ) ) ) )
```

Notice the new key value "keyboards" => array(... gets added AFTER the previous array gets closed. What I want it to look like is:

```
Array ( [messages] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [chatId] => d3a611401de00e8c8b3e225a7cf95484033f57ea18c442249ee9b5bcb63c9a96 [type] => text [to] => pitashi [body] => success [keyboards] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [type] => suggested [responses] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [type] => text [body] => Yes ) [1] => Array ( [type] => text [body] => No ) ) ) ) )
```

In the end I'm json encoding it. Here is a screenshot of how it looks and where I need it to be https://www.evernote.com/l/AETNv5OhBI1HtLzqXalq-BCfOIwz4U0jlWw and here is a screenshot of ultimately how I want it to look https://www.evernote.com/l/AETRjOREKvBHLpXyh3NdZdGAryyxO2rIiwg

I'm dumb. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Instead of such thing: `$arr_keyboards[] = ...` you actually want this: `$arr_keyboards = ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to add the `$arr_keyboards` array into the first element of the `$data["messages"]` array. 
Change the "*crucial*" line of code as following:

```
$data["messages"][0]["keyboards"] = $arr_keyboards;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$data["messages"][] = array(
    "chatId"    => $chat_id, 
    "type"      => "text", 
    "to"        => $username, 
    "body"      => "success"
);

$arr_keyboards = array(
    "type" => "suggested",
    "responses" => array(
        array("type" => "text", "body" => "Yes"), 
        array("type" => "text", "body" => "No")
    )
);

foreach ($data["messages"] as $message) {

    $message["keyboards"] = $arr_keyboards;
}

echo json_encode($message);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: ah. that does work. seems like overkill to have to loop back through instead of just appending, but it does work. Thanks @object-manipulator